# How to set a program to startup on boot for all users in windows 10?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10

I have to start some program when the computer boots, for all users, and possibly before the user login.

So how and where does I have to put them?

Comment: Do you have a C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see 3 ways

1. Task Scheduler has support to run it both in startup and in login
2. If the path I commented on OP exists you can drop an executable there
3. Registry. Don't do this if you don't know what you're doing, but they're in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>Run

For a beginner I'd recommend doing task scheduler since it's pretty and almost kinda debuggable.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 `shell:common startup` command in windows "run" can be used to open up startup folder and we can place script/batch files to be run during startup for all users.

Please check this link for more details [starup and common startup details](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8)